# Is there any tool allowing to locate app's elements on Android

Tags: android, automated-tests, location

Is there any possible way to locate app's elements on Android? I need to write tests for an app that sometimes show ads, but using appium inspector and debugging this app via PC this ads aren't showing up

Answer (score 0):

So, accidentally I found out how to catch and research apps' ads elements on Android. You shouldn't start session with your "Appium inspector" instead try to launch an app and when an add turns up then start "Appium inspector"